# AngularJS: when new data comes into a table previously checked radio button is showing up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

On my search page, when I search with one name I'm getting two records populated in the table with radio buttons. for example In that I selected second radio button. please find the image below
[image]

After that when I search with different name I'm getting 6 records populated on my table with radio buttons. But the table is showing up with previously checked radio button in the page. Please find the below value
[image]

My expectation is it should only populate the fresh data with unchecked radio buttons. but for me it is showing previously checked radio buttons. Can you please help how to resolve this.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="searchResult  in searchResultsArray track by $index">
    <td><input type="radio" id='regular' name="optradio" ng-checked="false" ng-click="setSelectedEmployee($index)"></td>
```

I tried below funtions but no luck in my controller:

```
$scope.tableParams.reload();
```

Comment: Show us some more code

Comment: Please find the HTML table details